# Web Audio API: performance problems?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I've got a little chime maker going here. It generates several overtones at once, and uses variable gain on each overtone to produce a rich chime sound. I call a function to play a series of these in sequence. But if I rapidly press the button a few times, the sound output stops, as though it's running out of memory:

https://codepen.io/ophello/pen/OJVRMQe

```js
function ding(freq) {
    var toneGen = new AudioContext()
    var duration = 15
    var T = toneGen.currentTime
    var overtones = [1,2.76,5.4,8.93,13.34,18.64]
    overtones.forEach(function(overtone,i) {
        var osc = toneGen.createOscillator()
        osc.type = "sine"
        var freqVal = freq * overtone
        if (freqVal <= 22050) {
            osc.frequency.value = freq * overtone
            var envelope = toneGen.createGain()
            osc.connect(envelope)
            envelope.gain.setValueAtTime(0.1/Math.pow((i+1),5), T)
            envelope.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.00001, T + duration)
            envelope.connect(toneGen.destination)
            osc.start(T)
            osc.stop(T + duration)
        }
    })
}

var hzValues = [216, 288, 324, 405, 432, 648]

$("#b1").mousedown(() => { 
    hzValues.forEach((thisHz,i) => { 
        setTimeout(() => { ding(thisHz) }, 100 * i); 
    })
})
```

Why does this stop working after a few presses? Am I missing something critical here? I don't know where in the console to look for any problems with this. Is this a memory issue?

Comment: needs more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/close ; you only get so many active contexts to use at once, which could be a browser or os or hardware limit.  "_it will forcibly release any system audio resources that might prevent additional AudioContexts from being created and used_" In other words, even though it's JS, you have to cleanup after yourself.

Comment: Then is there a way to achieve the result I want with fewer contexts? I'm not sure how to fix this. I already tell every oscillator to stop after a certain duration, isn't that the cleanup part?

Comment: you can destroy the ones that are not playing. you could also limit the count and round robin though an array of contexts if you need several active.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that. I tried using .close() but it halts all audio completely.

Comment: i can't break it permanently anymore if i add `setTimeout(toneGen.close.bind(toneGen), 3500);` after osc.stop(). Adjust as needed

Comment: That did the trick! I didn't know how to destroy the audio context.

Comment: Or just create the context outside of your function.  Everything should work, and you don't have to deal with creating and destroying so many heavy objects unnecessarily.

Comment: How would that work in the above code? I thought I needed a new context for every oscillator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to dandavis above, I got this working by adding a timeout function:

```
setTimeout(toneGen.close.bind(toneGen), duration*1000);
```

Update: Improved by moving the audio context outside the main function!